# Android - Update Status on Facebook from Android Application

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am trying to Update Status on Facebook from facebook using sdk version 3.14.1.

I am able to Update Status on Facebook from same account from which account created application in developers.facebook.

But couldn't post from different account. I had try lot but couldn't get solution.
Please give me a proper solution or reference link.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: turn off the sandbox mode in facebook developers page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi  @Kamlesh Arya my code is here

```
package com.mihir.fbdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.fbdemo.R;
import com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private Button btn_login = null, btn_post = null;
private TextView tv_welcome = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btn_post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
    tv_welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_welcome);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_post.setOnClickListener(this);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Can we present the share dialog for regular links?
    canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.btn_login:
        loginSession();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_post:
        onClickPostStatusUpdate();
        break;
    }
}

private void loginSession()
{
    // start Face-book Login
    Session.openActiveSession(Main.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
    {
        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {
            if (session.isOpened()) 
            {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                    {
                        if (user != null) 
                        {
                            tv_welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE &&
            (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
            exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
                .setTitle("Cancel")
                .setMessage("permission_not_granted")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                .show();
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
        handlePendingAction();
    }
//        updateUI();
}

private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
}

private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Log.e("performPublish", "performPublish");
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            // We can do the action right away.
            handlePendingAction();
            return;
        } else if (session.isOpened()) {
            // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
            return;
        }
    }

    if (allowNoSession) {
        pendingAction = action;
        handlePendingAction();
    }
}

 private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,
        POST_PHOTO,
        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

 private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

  @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        Log.e("handlePendingAction", "handlePendingAction");

        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

  private void postStatusUpdate() {
        Log.e("postStatusUpdate", "postStatusUpdate");

        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = "post from other account";
            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, null, null, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

  private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error) {
        String title = null;
        String alertMessage = null;
        if (error == null) {
            title = "success";
//              String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
            alertMessage = "successfully_posted_post";
        } else {
            title = "error";
            alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                .show();
    }

  private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
        return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setName("Hello Facebook")
                .setDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setLink("http://developers.facebook.com/android");
    }


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,

You need to `Disable testing mode on facebook developer console` then you will able to Update Status on Facebook from other account.

Analyse Facebook developer console you have a option in application setting menu.
and then set you application without testing mode.

Comment: I am facing same problem but in developer console i couldn't find the option for Disable testing mode under settings -> basic tab.

Comment: dosn't get solution yet plz help

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
1. Go to facebook developer
2. Select your app
3. Click "Status & Review" tab. Switch it to "YES" option
```

Comment: In my case its "YES". But i am not getting any error dialog or any success message...
I have used similar code as sample cod of Facebook-sdk "HelloFacebookSample".

Comment: my code is here


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905004/andorid-update-status-on-facebook-from-android-application/23906827#23906827